# Javascript/css: How to detect empty visual spaces in a list of div with different sizes

Tags: javascript, css, angular, algorithm

I made a stackblitz for understand my problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aqmahw?file=src/app/tiles-example.css

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rupgr.png)

I have tiles which can have 4 differents width (25%, 50%, 75%, 100%).

The tiles can only go on 2 lines, so if i have only tiles of 25% width i can have 8 of them.

I'm trying to find an algorithm to find the empty spaces in these 2 lines and what size are these empty spaces.
Because if I add a tile, I want it to be added in these empty spaces only if it has space and I don't want to add it to the end of the list.

Can someone help me with this algorithm ?

Comment: So you're ok with reordering the objects? In a sense that if your objects are initially of the sizes 1, 2, 3, 2 you can display them on rows like 1-3,2-2 or 2-2,1-3 and both would be acceptable?

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm or are you hoping some CSS can do this for you? I ask because one algorithm is very simple - just have 2 counters for the two rows starting with 4 in them and fit the next tile in if its width is less than one of these, and decrement the relevant counter accordingly. Stop when both counters are less than the next tile width.

Comment: @MishaMashina no reordering is impossible, in my project it would be impossible to have objects with the sizes 1, 2, 3, 2 because it would be on 3 lines.

Comment: @AHaworth i'm looking for an algorithm to tell me in the configuration of my screenshot:
There are 3 empty spaces at line 1 after object1.
But if the first object is size 3 and the second size 2, i want the algo to tell me:
There is 1 empty space at line 1 after object1 and 2 empty spaces at line 2 after object2.
The most important is to detect the empty spaces at line 1 for being able to add tile in these empty spaces if they exist.

Comment: You can see if there is empty space in line1, and how much of it there is, by looking at the counter for row 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example-list {
  --columns: 4;
  --gap: calc(8 / 16 * 1rem);
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--columns), 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: masonry;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.example-box {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: var(--gap);
  padding: var(--gap);
}

.example-box span {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.size-1 {
  grid-column: span 1 / auto;
}

.size-2 {
  grid-column: span 2 / auto;
}

.size-3 {
  grid-column: span 3 / auto;
}

.size-4 {
  grid-column: span 4 / auto;
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-list">
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-1"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-1"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-2"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-1"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-2"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-1"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-3"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-1"></div>
  <div _ngcontent-htr-c99="" class="example-box size-4"></div>
  <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"
}-->
</div>
```

You would be better off to achieve this using `grid` as you can control 2d space instead of `flex` 1d space

I rebuilt your example here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-teylho?file=src/app/tiles-example.ts

Comment: That's very neat idea! But I guess that reordering of the sizes of objects in the array will mess it up. Try having only 4 objects with sizes: 3, 2, 1, 2 -> they should be lined up in 2 rows, but are getting lined up in 3.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what I came up with: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n6dqoj?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftiles-example.ts

Beside your initial `tiles` object, I introduced variables that keep the data you might want changed (or set dynamically at any point):

- total size in a row (`maximumSizePerRow`) that you allow,
- total number of rows (`maximumNumberOfRows`) you want,
- starting name of a row (`rowPrefix`) for displaying/logging purpose,

along with two arrays of objects that keep the information about rows' content and are used to handle adding new tiles:

- `rowsData` that keeps info about the row (name, empty spaces left and names of the tiles that are set into this row),
- `tilesUsed` that keeps only the tiles that are going to be displayed - depending on the number of rows you want to display i.e. tiles that don't fall into the last allowed row won't be in this object. This object is then used in template instead of your original `tiles` object.

The algorithm is very simple in this case: after initial structure of the `rowsData` is set, the code iterates over the rows objects in that array, and inside each iteration iterates again over the tiles from `tiles` object: if certain criteria is met - it puts the given tile into the row. The criteria is that row size is not full, it has enough space for that particular tile, and the tile is not already used in another row.

So in the view you'll only see the tiles that are used in the allowed number of rows, and the final console log is just a decoration, but shows which data to use to get empty spaces left per row.